# windows phone 8 show blank map

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add a simple map to my app.

I added map reference, added capability in WMAppManifest and this code to page:

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" Center="47.6097, -122.3331" ZoomLevel="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="Map_Loaded_1"  />

    </Grid>
```

but it show blank map. What I mean blank? a black page!

I can not get it to work. tell me what I missed!?

Comment: Does it show in the designer? Have you added other content to the page to verify that the page is loaded? Do any of the page level events (constructor, OnNavigatedTo, Loaded, etc.) or your Loaded event handler get called? Have you declared the `ID_CAP_MAP` capability in your project?

Comment: yes other objects displayed correctly. and yes I added ID_CAP_MAP.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project that enables us to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this guide step by step, and see if it helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your internet connection is dead (or just not configured properly in emulator)?